# Add TagLib library to Linux Qt project in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, taglib

I have installed `taglib1-dev`. But can't figure out how to include it in my project in Qt Creator. And how do I include taglib headers? I have seen explanations for Windows, none for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out for myself. You have to apt install `libtag1-dev`. And then just include the header (.h) files in your qt program. In your `.pro` file, you have to add `LIBS += -ltag` and then run `qmake`.